# Integrating Calendar Function into Static .html Site

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, google-calendar-api

I need to build a calendar function into an HTML site. I'm looking for some way to grab a snippet of code off of something like a Google Calendar to put into a div on my website. The goal is that my client can manage their calendar on their own.

I'm a professional SEO who moonlights as a web designer. I'm fairly savvy with HTML and CSS, but that's about it - I only build small sites with generally static content. If I can grab a Facebook or Twitter feed, I feel like I should be able to do the same with a calendar function.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a calendar implemented in JavaScript? If so, you could just put **[Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html#site)** straight into the page.

Another good alternative is **[fullCalendar](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar)**, but this does have a dependency on the jQuery JavaScript library.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Styled Calendar](https://styledcalendar.com). You can connect it to a public Google calendar, but add some styling enhancements. You can then use the embed code in the static site.

Your client will be able to update the calendar from their Google Calendar dashboard.